# Mvc OAuth2 how to store data for the current Autentication in a OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity

im sorry for my bad English, im french. 
I will try to explain my question the best i can.

i have a [OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.oauth.oauthauthorizationserverprovider%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) **wish work fine**.

This is to allow other application to connect with my Asp.Net Identity 2.0 Authentication Server.

I wish to store data for the current authentication. If the user is connected twice, they will not necessary have the same stored data. I don't think Session is the right thing for this becose i dont use cookie. I use [Bearer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/09/20/understanding-security-features-in-spa-template.aspx), an access_token and a refresh_token.

I can simply store the refresh_token in a table, then refer it on each request but i don't like to store sensible data like that, especially if the framework provide a way to do what i want.

**I need to store the data relative to each external authentication, not to the user**. Something like Claims but only for the current authentication session.

tanks to point me on the right path.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?  I don't understand how Claims are not suitable for your scenario.

Comment: Maybe i dont understand claims, i did not really use it. But as i see in the schema, it's related to the user and its not related to the current session. and stay on the server. Is a user can have 2 claims with the same name and different values? Like if a user is loged with chrome and firefox. Theyr is 2 session for the same user.

Comment: The user claims are encoded into the token.  I think all you need to do is just add the specific additional claims to the identity in your `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider`.

Comment: if you can add an answer with an example or documentation/tutorial, i will test it tomorrow and if it work i will accept the answer. I allow wish to know how the user is connected: by my website(CookieAuthenticationProvider) or by OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider.Do i need to add claims on my CookieAuthenticationProvider? like authtype = "external" or authtype = "local"  

Tanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider`, you will have overridden the `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` method.  This is where you will have validated the user, and it's the place where you can add additional claims for the user.

Here is an example that validates the user against `ASPNet Identity`, and adds an additional claim to the identity that is returned.

```
    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

        var mgr = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

        var user = await mgr.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);
        if (user == null)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            return;
        }

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        var usrIdentity = await mgr.CreateIdentityAsync(user, context.Options.AuthenticationType);

        foreach (var c in usrIdentity.Claims)
        {
            identity.AddClaim(c);
        }

        //
        // Add additional claims to your identity
        //
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("your_custom_claim", "your_custom_claim_value"));

        context.Validated(identity);
    }
```

That said, in your comments you seem to be using Cookie and Token in the same sentence, and possibly confusing the two.  Check out [this blog post](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/) which should give you a good example.

Also check out the [ASP.NET Identity Recommended Resources](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/aspnet-identity-recommended-resources) page too.